# Job responsibilities - developer Cv

Tags: resume, career-development, software-development, careers

I have a short summary in my job responsibilities which looks like:

> Development and maintenance of internal web applications using
>    HTML, CSS, Javascript, React.js, Ext JS.

However, there is one problem I have with it.
Particularly I *think* it implies (the way it is written in English) that if I developed say a single web application then I used *ALL* the technologies listed there. Which is *not* the case and not even possible in some cases.

However, what I want is a summary sentence, which implies that I might have developed say 3 (or more) web apps, and in one I used *only* Ext JS, in other only HTML/CSS maybe combined with React.

Comment: "web application**s**" has already implied that it's more than one application. If you really want to highlight it more you can say "Development and maintenance of **multiple** internal web applications". Of course, don't really use bold like me in your CV ;)

Comment: @tweray OP here: couldn't finish account creation, so replying to you here: that is not what the question asks :).

Comment: @giorgim I am not sure what you want to ask about then. The sentence clearly implied what did you do (maintain multiple web applications) and what are the technology involved (HTML, CSS, Javascript, React.js, Ext JS). I don't see by any way it can really be interpreted into `one (or each) of these applications involve all the technologies listed`.

Comment: @tweray I *think* in english the way it is written it implies that EACH web app I wrote is written using ALL of the tech listed.

Comment: You could say something like "using various combinations of ... techs ... for each application" but that sounds pretty stiff.  I think what would be more interesting would be to list what some of those apps actually do, e.g. "Applications include sales order fulfillment, inventory, ...".  No one really cares about the details of which app used which tech, as long as you actually know the different techs you are listing.

Comment: As a hiring manager, it would be nice to know what these applicatons did (in general terms) and not just what tech you used. If you really wanted, you could separate individual applications to show where you used specific tech. If you did more than 3 or 4, then pick the ones you think will be the most impressive.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is more of an English language question than a Workplace question.  I think it would work much better on that stack.

Comment: Many developers use skill bars or bar charts to list skills, say for example html/css: 90% Javascript: 80% React.Js: 70% and so on

Answer (score 12):

You're overthinking this.

> Particularly I think it implies (the way it is written in English) that if I developed say a single web application then I used ALL the technologies listed there.

It doesn't.

I certainly didn't read it like that, and I'd imagine most other people wouldn't either. If they *do* misread it, then it also doesn't really matter - it's hardly like they're going to get an impression that's a million miles off from what you're doing.

Answer (score 4):

I'm a native English speaker and I wouldn't assume that.

If it makes you feel better you can use this:

> Developed and maintained multiple internal web applications using HTML, CSS, Javascript, React.js, Ext JS.

or this

> Development and maintenance of internal web applications (HTML, CSS, Javascript, React.js, Ext JS)

Answer (score 0):

Your CV's job (resume's job) is to get you the interview. That's it. So list your experience.

The job of the hiring manager, during the interview, is to figure out whether your experience meets their needs. She will ask you detailed questions to understand what you can do.

Any hiring manager worth her salt knows that you don't use every kind of technology on every project.

In all cases tell the truth. But don't overthink your CV. Seriously.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @JChrisCompton +1

However, if you want another alternative and be sure that any ambiguity is removed, you may use:

> Development and maintenance of **several** internal web applications, using **(where applicable)**: HTML, CSS, Javascript, React.js, Ext JS

(highlight only used for emphasizing the modification)